# SilverStripe Template

Tags: templates, silverstripe

**SilverStripe 2.4.7**

Hi

I'm trying to put together a template to structure my JSON.  My classes have relationships as follows.

A store can have many offers and many news articles.  Offers and news articles can belong to many stores.

My template looks like this

```
{
"StoresHolder" : [
<% control Children %>
{
    "ID" : "$ID",
    "Name" : "$Name",
    "Address1" : "$Address1",
    "Address2" : "$Address2",
    "County" : "$County",
        "News"  : [
            <% control News %>
            {
            "ID" : "$ID",
            "Title" : "$Title",
            "DatePublished" : "$DatePublished",
            "ExpiryDate" : "$ExpiryDate",
            "Body" : "$Body",
            "URL" : "$URL",
            "Photo" : "$Photo.Filename"
            }<% if Middle %>,<% end_if %>
            <% end_control %>
        ],
        "Offers" : [
            <% control Offers %>
            {
            "ID" : "$ID",
            "Title" : "$Title",
            "Description" : "$Description",
            "Weight" : "$Weight",
            "Price" : "$Price",
            "Savings" : "$Savings",
            "Expires" : "$Expires",
            "Photo" : "$Photo.Filename"
            }<% if Middle %>,<% end_if %>
            <% end_control %>
        ]
}<% if Last %> <% else %>,<% end_if %>
<% end_control %>
]
}
```

I got it working to the point that it displays only one of the offers and news articles but I can't get any further. Any advice is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look right - in the sense of: Have you taken a look at something like this:

```
$data = DataObject::get(...); 
$formatter = new JSONDataFormatter(); 
return $formatter->convertDataObjectSet($data);
```

Combined with the proper handling of [DataObjectSets](http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/sapphire/model/DataObjectSet.html), this should be a better approach.
Unless you have very specific reasons for requiring something different - then please state them

Comment: I fully agree with xeraa here, you should not build the json in template

Comment: if for some reason you can not use DataObjectsSets and a formater, you can also build up arrays and convert them to json with $json = Convert::array2json($array);

http://paste2.org/p/2318703

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. So I should scrap the template altogether and take this approach?  Am I right in thinking this should be located in the controller?

Comment: exactly, you don't need a template :)

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I'll try this out and see how it goes.  What did you mean by "proper handling of DataObjectSets" though?

Comment: Only that you need to build the DataObjectSet according to your output needs with the available methods. And I've used ``Convert::array2json()`` in a project as well - working fine, but IMHO a little less SilverStripe-ish :)

Comment: Oh ok. I see.  Thanks for your help. I may need to ask another question about this before I'm finished though. :)

Comment: Ok last question and I'm sorry in advance for it being so obvious but how does this get accessed? What I mean is when I enter the URL I should see JSON but how?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.silverstripe.org/data-model-questions/show/15194 for example (you might require setting the proper permissions as well). Be sure to name your **public** method according to the URL you want to use.